# Android HTTP connection and stream "gathering"

Tags: android, eclipse, http

I "wrote" some code which should execute http request + stream download, however it does not seem to be working with the second part. It connects to the server, but without getting the expected data from it. The first few times it evena worked out, it displayed the html data from google, but afterwards,
 I tried to optimize my code and threw something away, added something here and there, extended it by a class etc., which probably caused the "error". Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TAG = null;
TextView httpStuff;
public static String  info;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try {
        AsyncDownload data = (AsyncDownload) new AsyncDownload().execute();
        info = data.get();
        httpStuff.setText(info);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public class AsyncDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Final Requsting URL is : :" + "google.com");

        String line = "";
        String responseData = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String x = "";
            URL httpurl = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            URLConnection  tc = httpurl.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                x = sb.toString();
            }
            responseData = new String(x);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uh){            
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Unknown host :");
            uh.printStackTrace();
        }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           Log.v("NewWebHelper", "FileNotFoundException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "IOException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Exception :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseData;
    }

}
```

I just don't know what's the missing thing. I've been trying to solve this for hours with a big variety of data-passing versions of this, but nothing seems to be working. I'm counting on you, brainiacs.

Comment: Ouch, problem solved on my own. I forgot to initialize my httpStuff textview with the actual textview in my activity. I just filled some random textview object in the air with that data and was wondering what's wrong. 10hours of thinking paid off!